# Precompiled Contracts called from Off-chain

Tags: evm, precompiled-contracts

Is it possible to call a precompiled contract from an off-chain application?
Precompiled contracts' addresses are 0x01, 0x02, ... and I know that it is perfectly possible to send a transaction to those addresses with some data, nothing would technically failed, but I do not know if I would actually get a returned value.

For instance:
Calling precompiled contract **sha256** (address :0x02), passing it some bytes and get the bytes32 hash in return.

*This is a pure theoretical question, precompiled contracts are supposed to perform complex functionality that do not alter the state of the blockchain which means that you could do exactly the same off-chain....*